# SimpleXML parsing has strange effect on strings

Tags: php, xml, substring

I want to get `13:00` and `13:50` using `new SimpleXMLElement()` on

```
<time>
    <start_time>01:00PM</start_time>
    <end_time>01:50</end_time>
</time>
```

I tried this:

```
$stime = $some_child_element->start_time;
$etime = $some_child_element->end_time;
if($stime[strlen($stime)-2] == 'P') {
    $stime = (substr($stime,0,2)+12) . substr($stime,2,3);
    $etime = (substr($etime,0,2)+12) . substr($etime,2,3);
}
else
    $stime = substr($stime,0,5);

echo $stime;
```

but it doesn't do anything. Then I tried to cast the time with `(string)value` and still nothing. `echo` and `strlen` work, but array-like access and substring don't work and it doesn't show anything, neither errors...

**EDIT:** The problem here is not only how do I make that a datetime, but on how I can access a smaller set of this string. Substring doesn't work, neither `$time[0]`

Check out this demo:
http://codepad.viper-7.com/vdmlVQ

Comment: Did you try creating a `DateTime` object? You can format it any way you want. Check the PHP docs.

Comment: When you say "it doesn't do anything", what do you mean? You get an empty output? The whole string as output?

Comment: yes empty output with substring or char access

Comment: How do you creat xml object? You have to cast `$some_child_element->start_time` to string.

Comment: did that too, the same, said it on question after the php code

Comment: If that is the structure of your time tag then you have to access it differently, like `$some_child_element->time[0]->start_time`

Comment: can you check out the demo i provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was when casting the element into string, the actual string started from position 1. very strange... See the demo below

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/RFDeTb)

Answer (score 1):

You made this *much* more complicated then it needed to be. Just use PHP's built in date/time functionality to do the converting for you:

```
$time = $some_child_element->time;
echo date('H:i', strtotime($time));
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/rrmCHR)

Comment: This answer still applies. It shows you exactly how to transform the original dates into the format you want.

Comment: this is not my only question